# Developer Documentation makes Xcode crash

Tags: xcode

in Xcode, clicking on developer documentation or (Shift + Command + 0) makes xCode crash and quit. Current version is: **Version 12.0 (12A7209)**

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this crash by removing the install from Mac App Store and downloading Xcode 12 from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: This solved the problem, although this will load Version 12.0 (12A7209) as well…